# How to initially show the upload button in async method in kendo ui upload control

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui upload control. In that i am using async method. I have defined the
upload control like

```
      $("#files").kendoUpload({
           async:{
              saveUrl:"/Home/Image",
              removeUrl:"/Home/RemoveImage"
          }
      });
```

what i need is that when i select any file then the upload button is coming. But i want the button initially and when i select any file then only the upload button should enable.
How can i do that in kendo ui. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, no Upload button is created until files are added to the upload control.

What you can do is to create your own custom upload button and hide the original one using CSS ex:

```
.k-upload-selected{
       display: none;
}
```

and then you can enable/disable your custom button on the upload events "select" and "complete" from the upload control and to call the upload event form you custom button like :

```
$('#yourCustomUploadButton').click( function() {
    $('.k-upload-selected').trigger('click');
});
```

I hope this help you.